# Bad Header response received for Facebook oauth header

Tags: facebook-oauth

For google found that the oauth header format is

```
    GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=1.0,oauth_nonce=5887e5b11904194f7d217e9b7f795d62, oauth_timestamp=1317623602,
oauth_consumer_key=56565768768.apps.googleusercontent.com",oauth_verifier=PH9etu_6shPOPvlFgiFJS-Dd,
oauth_token=4%2Fpdn5ZtajHsU-zeSxScNSil43sTK0,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,
oauth_signature=ybgad%2B6LlQ8P3rwnFa8BpI8awok%3D
Content-Length: 353
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
```

Seeing this made a request header for facebook as

```
    Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=1.0,oauth_nonce=5887e5b11904194f7d217e9b7f795d62, oauth_timestamp=1317623602,
oauth_consumer_key=12904260719,oauth_verifier=PH9etu_6shPOPvlFgiFJS-Dd,
oauth_token=4%2Fpdn5ZtajHsU-zeSxScNSil43sTK0,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,
oauth_signature=ybgad%2B6LlQ8P3rwnFa8BpI8awok%3D
Content-Type: application/X-WWW-form-urlencoded
```

What's the mistake in this header

Can anyone help me out please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved. Facebook is not expecting a header which contains parameters like oauth_nounce,  oauth_consumer_key etc